# Cannot send automatic notification?

Tags: facebook, notifications, send, sendmessage

I'm writing an app, and i am able to get my code to send a notification to the user that has authenticated my app.

As long as i open the php page in a browser, it sends a notification to the user. This works like a charm, until i try to get the code to send a notification without the user initiating it.

I keep running into trouble with tokens, and just cannot get it to work. I've tried saving access tokens to my database, and letting the code use those tokens, to no avail. I've then tried to exchange those tokens for long lived tokens, that all works fine, i get tokens with a 60 day expiration date, but when i try using those, it just does not work.

Does anyone have any experience with letting an app send a notification or message? I'm out of ideas here..

Edit
I'll elaborate a bit on how i did things, and what does and does not work:
I'm using the php sdk for most things, like initializing the app:

```
  require_once("facebook.php");

  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = 'xxxx';
  $config['secret'] = 'xxxx';
  $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

I then check if the user has logged in, if not, send him to the login page etc:

```
if($user_id) {
 try {
  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=friends.fields(picture,name,gender,link),name','GET');
  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
  header( $login_url ) ;
 }   
} else {
 $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
 header( $login_url ) ;
}
```

Then, my app draws the html etc, works fine.
At the end of the code, i exchange the user acces_token for a long-lived token:

```
$existingtoken = $access_token;
$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $config['appId'] .
                "&client_secret=" . $config['secret'] .
                "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token" .
                "&fb_exchange_token=" . $existingtoken;

$new_app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
$new_app_token = str_replace("access_token=", "", $new_app_token);

$NewToken = str_replace("&expires=", "", $new_app_token);

$mystring = $new_app_token;
$findme   = '&expires=';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
// check if the token actually is long-lived and has the expires data
if ($pos === false) {                                                       
    echo "Error getting long lived token.<br>";
} else {
$expirationtime = substr($mystring, ((int)$pos+9));
}
```

Until now, everything just works well. I can even send notifications using this code (it took me a day to actually get this to work, the information about this is not found easily):

```
$notificationdata = array(
    'href'=> 'https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/',
    'access_token'=> $app_token,
    'template'=> '180 char string as information'
);
$sendnotification = $facebook->api('/' . $user_id . '/notifications', 'post', $notificationdata);
```

EDIT2:
Actually, i have it working now:)

Comment: I havent yet worked with sending notification, but if you face problems with access_tokens, sure let us know the the errors you get, and show us your code. We can be of help.

Comment: If you have it working now, could you add an answer here explaining what the problem was, or delete the question? as-is, this isn't useful to other people encountering the issue